# Alternative to an SQL Update inside a Loop

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to check two columns in a database (start_date and end_date). If the end_date is greater than the start_date, then I wish to update a record.

Is there a better way to do this other than to have an UPDATE SQL query inside the loop?

```
$current_date = time();
echo 'current_date '. $current_date .'<br>';

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo 'start_date '. $row['start_date'] .' - end_date '. $row['end_date'] .' - ';

    if ($current_date >= $row['end_date'])
    {
        echo 'UPDATE SQL HERE?';
    }
        else
    {
        echo 'Leave the data alone';
    }
}
```

I'm after the best method for performance ideally. My first thought is to perhaps to loop through the results and add each one into an array - then to update the array? I'm not sure how I would do this though if it is indeed a method.

Comment: What do the DB dates look like?

Comment: Unix timestamp (1436948336 for example)

Comment: If this update page only updates the `end_date` Column you can easily compare with a `WHERE` statement. But if that page can edit also the `start_date` Column, you can always make a check with php before even start a `sql` query.

Comment: This seems to work - `$query = "UPDATE business SET upgrade = '0', start_date = '', end_date = '', status = '' WHERE upgrade = 1 AND end_date >= {$current_date}";` - I'm wanting to update a number of rows where the current date is LESS than the end date

Answer (score 1):

If all rows are to be updated to `someValue` then you can do this:

`UPDATE tableName SET expired = 'someValue' WHERE current_date >= end_date;`

I am of course assuming some kind of expiration is being measured.

Comment: Hm... so instead of retrieving the data... I could just directly update it? I never thought of that